# html2canvas export functionality doesn't work

Tags: javascript, download, html2canvas

I was following a solution in order to implement the html2canvas function. ([How to show scrollable all contents of div in pdf using html2canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53178306/how-to-show-scrollable-all-contents-of-div-in-pdf-using-html2canvas))
The answer of one of the users is just working fine, when executing the respective function in jsfiddle.net (https://jsfiddle.net/dr4ewfa1/5/). However, after copying + pasting the same code in visual study, I don't receive any download files after clicking the button.

Do you have an idea, why this could be & how to solve this ?
My HTML file looks like this, the JS code is exactly the same as mentioned by the user @Nimitt Shah:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#print').click(function() {
    var currentPosition = document.getElementById("content").scrollTop;
     var w = document.getElementById("content").offsetWidth;
     var h = document.getElementById("content").offsetHeight;
    document.getElementById("content").style.height="auto";

     html2canvas(document.getElementById("content"), {
        
       dpi: 300, // Set to 300 DPI
       scale: 3, // Adjusts your resolution
       onrendered: function(canvas) {
         var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1);
         var doc = new jsPDF('L', 'px', [w, h]);
         doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 0, 0, w, h);
         doc.addPage();
         doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
       }
     });
    document.getElementById("content").style.height="100px";
    document.getElementById("content").scrollTop = currentPosition;
   });
   
   });
```

```css
body {
  background: beige;
}

header {
  background: red;
}

footer {
  background: blue;
}

#content {
  background: yellow;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
.html2canvas-container { width: 3000px !important; height: 3000px !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.4.1/jspdf.min.js">
</script>
<div id="content">
      <p>This is the element you only want to capture</p>   
       <p>This is the element you only want to capture</p>  
        <p>This is the element you only want to capture</p> 
         <p>This is the element you only want to capture</p>    
          <p>This is the element you only want to capture</p>   
    </div>
    <button id="print">Download Pdf</button>
    <footer>This is the footer</footer>
```

I also executed the following statement in the console/terminal: `npm install --save html2canvas`
Unfortunately i still didn't get any file.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I realized, that I'm also not able to execute the code in here. maybe it's the same reason ?

Comment: I know there are dependencies to jspdf, among which html2Canvas. I actually experienced a very strange thing: for my own purpose  (inserting html data into a canvas, then canvas.toDataURL), version 1.4.1 of html2Canvas would not respond, while v. 0.4.1 did. I retrieved v. 0.4.1 here: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js. Good luck.